# What do HSDZ and HYDZ mean for piezo buzzers?

Tags: piezo-buzzer

I have some buzzers, which have a label on them, which states "HSDZ REMOVE SEAL AFTER WASHING". I know that washing is the process of removing residues of flux or something else with solvent. However, I can't find anything about HSDZ. What does it mean? Some buzzers on the internet have HYDZ instead. What do those letters mean?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be lots of different clusters of letters out there, and some have none at all. As far as I can tell, this isn't a specification or a message of some sort.

Presumably it's something as simple as the initials of the manufacturer.

[image: Buzzer Pictures With Different Letters]

Comment: Ok, I have just found out this: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/THDZ-KC12095-Passive-active-Electromagnetic-Buzzer_770455482.html
there it is referred as "Model".